# Where exactly is the clear completed button for tasks in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

All the docs and answers for Gmail Tasks refer to the **Clear completed tasks** button or link but I can't actually find it. Anyone know where it might be?

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the Tasks window within Gmail
2. Click on **Actions**
3. Click on **Clear completed tasks** at the bottom of the menu list

[image]